# Python get least significant digits from a float (without using string operations)

Tags: python, floating-point, int, bit-manipulation

Assuming I have the float 12345.6789 and I want to get the six least significant digits (i.e. 45.6789) as an int (i.e. 456789) using bit operations in python (v. 2.6).

How do I do that?

Thanks

PS I do not want to use string operations even if it would be rather easy to: for any float f:

```
int(str(int(f * 1000))[-10:])
```

EDIT:  This original question is pointless, as shown by comments within.  Many apologies... instead methods on getting the least significant digits without using strings are shown below (using ints and modulus)

Comment: """I do not want to use string operations""" - why not? is this homework or do you have enough time for finding solutions other than the most obvious solutions?

Comment: What would be the 6 least significant digits of `1/11=0.09090909...`?

Comment: You want the 6 least significant **decimal** digits but you want to do it using **bit** operations? Since when was 10 an integer power of 2?

Comment: @Ishtar the float representation on a machine is finite... so I'd just take the six LSB of that finite representation

Comment: @John I was thinking you could convert the float in a bit, work with that and convert it back ... wouldn't this work?

Comment: In that case since `12345.6789` is represented as `12345.678900000001` shouldn't the answer be `1`?

Comment: @RestRisiko - I am 32 years old.  No this is not "homework" - I am just looking for a more elegant solution then the 3 way conversion, truncation one I displayed above.

Comment: @MalteseUnderdog: The float representation of `0.1` decimal is `0.0001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011...` (and so on, ad infinitum) in binary. So there is no correspondence of significant digits between decimal and binary floats.

Comment: @gnibbler - mmmm, I hadn't thought of that... you are right obviously

Comment: @MalteseUnderdog: What does "convert the float in a bit" mean? What does the "B" in "6 LSB" mean? Bit? Byte? Remember you want decimal digits ...

Comment: Ok -- the question is pointless then... how do I close/kill it?

Comment: the question is absolutely pointless as implictly mentioned earlier

Comment: You can flag it for moderator attention and ask for removal. But why not leave it here, it's interesting enough and has made several people think :)

Comment: As someone who found this useful, I wanted to say that although this was not possible "bitwise", I think the underlying idea was actually to use mathematical operations versus string ones.  You could just modify the terminology of your question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
>>> a = 12345.6789
>>> b = int(a*10000)
>>> b
123456789
>>> c = b % 1000000
>>> c
456789
```

But - WHY??

Comment: This is not using "bit operations", but they make even less sense in this context.

Comment: Just a question: Is this more efficient in terms of speed then the string truncation solution?

Comment: @MalteseUnderdog yes, by a factor of 50. But it's unlikely to matter unless you're doing millions of these conversions.

Answer (score 3):

Relevant for your string solution is that the float display algorithm changed in python 2.7:

```
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Sep 15 2010, 15:52:39) 
>>> 12345.6789
12345.678900000001

Python 2.7.0+ (r27:82500, Sep 15 2010, 18:04:55) 
>>> 12345.6789
12345.6789
```

Whether you use one or the other, there's a problem knowing what, exactly, is the precision of a floating point number. Say your algorithm is given the float 1.23. What's the precision? Maybe it was stored as 1.230, but it just happened to end with a zero digit. So you must know how many digits after the period you wish to preserve.

Also, bit operations do not work on floats:

```
>>> 12345.6789 << 4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for <<: 'float' and 'int'
```

So you must multiply the float by your known precision and use modulo (%), as suggested by other posters.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> int(12345.6789*10000)%1000000
456789
```

but that is not *bit operations*